# Using grepl() in a for loop to fuzzy match

Tags: r

I have two data-frames that look like this:

```
matcher<-data.frame(matcher.nation=c("","",""),matcher.var=c("test one","test two", "example one"))
matcher <- data.frame(lapply(matcher, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
matcher
  matcher.nation matcher.var
1                   test one
2                   test two
3                example one
```

and

```
df<-data.frame(var=c("test","example"),nation=c("AFG","BEL"))
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df
      var nation
1    test    AFG
2 example    BEL
```

Now I want to do some kind of fuzzy matching to fill in `matcher$matcher.nation`. Therefore, I've written the following loop:

```
for (i in length(df$var)){
  matcher$matcher.nation[grepl(paste(".*",df$var[i],".*",sep=""),
                               matcher$matcher.var)]<-df$nation[i]
}
```

that is supposed to iterate through `df$var`, compare it to `matcher$matcher.var`, and match `df$nation` to `matcher$matcher.nation` if the expression is found in `matcher` (no matter what comes before or after the expression).

If I do this, it matches just one nation:

```
matcher
  matcher.nation matcher.var
1                   test one
2                   test two
3            BEL example one
```

However, if I do it manually for i=1 (i.e. use "test" in grepl), it works perfectly fine:

```
matcher$matcher.nation[grepl(paste(".*","test",".*",sep=""),matcher$matcher.var)]<-"AFG"
matcher
  matcher.nation matcher.var
1            AFG    test one
2            AFG    test two
3            BEL example one
```

If anyone could point me in the direction of what's wrong with my loop that would be nice.
Thanks!

Comment: The problem is in the loop counter, you have `i in length(df$var)`. You need `i in 1:length(df$var)`.

Comment: The `lapply` with stringsAsFactors is unnecessary. Just add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to the initial data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
for (i in 1:length(df$var)) {
```

Or, even better,

```
for (i in seq_along(df$var)) {
```

An extra tip: instead of `paste(..., sep="")`, you can use `paste0(...)`.